# Filtering NSArray with NSDictionary Objects using NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have a NSArray that contains dictionary objects. The structure of array looks like this:

```
Data = (
    {
    Date = "07/11/2013";
    LotNumber = 1;
    PartyName = "Gaurav Wadhwani";
    Quantity = 500;
},
    {
    Date = "07/11/2013";
    LotNumber = 2;
    PartyName = "Gaurav Wadhwani";
    Quantity = 600;
}
)
```

I am using a Search and Display controller which allows the user to search through `LotNumber`, `PartyName` or `Date`. I know how to use Scope titles and search bar. However, I am unable to use NSPredicate to get correct results. This is my code:

```
NSString *searchParameter = @"LotNumber";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@", searchParameter, searchText];
    filteredGoodsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
NSLog(@"Filtered Array = %@", filteredGoodsArray);
```

I always get blank results in filtered array. Could you tell me what's wrong here?

Thank You.

Comment: Is `LotNumber` an `NSNumber` in the dictionary?

Comment: I set it using [dict setObject:lotNo forKey:@"LotNumber"]; . But even if its NSNumber, the above code doesn't work when I search for PartyName as well.

Comment: Have you debugged to check everything it set to the values you expect?

Comment: @Wain Yeah I NSLog'd the array which is not filtered, and it logs correct data to console.

Comment: Log the predicate too.

Comment: @Wain done. The predicate log shows: Predicate: PartyName CONTAINS[cd] "Gaurav"
in the console

Comment: 'data' is the array that contains all the data. 'filteredGoodsArray' is the array where i am trying to filter and store results in. From what I see in code, I am "trying" to filter the correct array :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40807/discussion-between-wain-and-gaurav-wadhwani)

Comment: @gaurav, did you try using NSArray only like that  filteredGoodsArray=[data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"Filtered Array = %@", filteredGoodsArray);

Answer (score 2):

You can use **-predicateWithBlock:** to filter your dataArray

```
- (NSArray *)filterArray:(NSArray *)dataArray WithSearchText:(NSString *)searchText ScopeTitle:(NSString *)scopeTitle {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        //this is the dictionary in your dataArray
        NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)evaluatedObject;
        NSString *key = @"";

        //get key based on your selected scope
        if ([scopeTitle isEqualToString:@"Lot"])
            key = @"LotNumber";
        else if ([scopeTitle isEqualToString:@"Party"])
            key = @"PartyName";

        //grab the value from the dictionary with the corresponding key
        NSString *value = [dictionary objectForKey:key];

        //if the value contains your searchText return YES to add the object to the filtered array
        //if not it returns NO to filter it out of the array
        return [value rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound;
    }];

    //filter your dataArray using the predicate
    return [dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```